# Double DLL exports when using .DEF file with alias

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015, linker, dllexport

I use a .DEF file to build a Win32 DLL with VS-2015 (Intel compiler). The .DEF file looks like this:

EXPORTS
a=my_func

The problem is that the DLL has two exports for the function and I'm not using any dllexport(...) stuff:

Ordinal   Entry Point   Name
        1   0x00002160    a
        2   0x00002160    my_func

How can I avoid this? I just want to export the functions with the name given in the .DEF file.

Comment: I assume that you *want* the function to be exported with a name other than its internal name? Otherwise, you could just put `my_func` in the EXPORTS file.

Comment: Yes, I want to export it with a different name, that's why I use the .DEF file.

Comment: Works as expected here (as verified with `dumpbin /exports`) i.e. the export table has a single entry for the renamed `a`. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).